# How to handle callback when mail is sent in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I wonder how to handle the callback when mail is sent? I want to do some action when the mail is sent. I know the code below is wrong, let's say $callbackOnSend is called before the mail is send and $callbackAfterSent is called after the mail is sent.

```
Mail::send(array('text' => 'view'), $data, $callbackOnSend, $callbackAfterSent);
```

I wonder how can I achieve the $callbackAfterSent?

Answer (score -2):

If the mail is sent, the Mail::send() method will return true.

```
$mailVariables = ['from' => 'abc@abc.com'. 'fromName' => 'abc', 'to' => '123@123.com', 'cc' => 'xyz@xyz.com', 'attachment' => 'file1'];

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($mailVariables)
{
    $message->from($mailVariables['from'], $mailVariables['fromName']);

    $message->to($mailVariables['to'])->cc($mailVariables['cc']);

    $message->attach($mailVariables['attachment']);
});
```

If you need to do something if/after the mail is sent, you can wrap the whole Mail::send() in an if statement, however, from what I've read, it won't work if you have 'pretent' set to true in your config as with 'pretend' set to true, mail::send() will always return false.

```
if(Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($mailVariables)
    {
        $message->from($mailVariables['from'], $mailVariables['fromName']);

        $message->to($mailVariables['to'])->cc($mailVariables['cc']);

        $message->attach($mailVariables['attachment']);
    })) {
// do something
}
```